# Hive Query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I don't need the entire table to export, I need to add a query (`select * from emp_data where dept = 'cse'`) to the sqoop statement and the output should be exported to MySql. I tried the below statement but it didn't work.

```
sqoop export  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test  --username root  --password root  --table emp_data --query SELECT * from emp_data where dept = 'cse'--fields-terminated-by '\t' --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/emp_data/emp_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --query argument can not be used with sqoop export tool.
You can use --query argument in sqoop import tool, whick import data from mysql to hdfs.
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_3

Comment: Thanks! i copied the output of query to another hive table and exported that table directly to mysql.